# Array in value of hash perl

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, reference

Is it possible to assign the reference of an array as the value in the `key : value` pair of a hash table in perl?

Comment: Have a look at the [data structures cookbook](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html#HASHES-OF-ARRAYS).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Yes it is. Create a reference to the array by using backslash:

```
$hash{key} = \@array;
```

Note that this will link to the actual array, so if you perform a change such as:

```
$array[0] = "foo";
```

That will also mean that `$hash{key}[0]` is set to `"foo"`.

If that is not what you want, you may copy the values by using an anonymous array reference `[ ... ]`:

```
$hash{key} = [ @array ];
```

Moreover, you don't have to go through the array in order to do this. You can simply assign directly:

```
$hash{key} = [ qw(foo bar baz) ];
```

Read more about making references in [perldoc perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Making-References)

Comment: maybe some words about autovivification?:) it is good to know for beginner

Comment: @loldop Well, yes, many things are good to know for a beginner, however, here we are not talking about autovivification, just simple scalar values being assigned.

Comment: I think you meant "eq 'foo'" not "== 'foo'"

Answer (score 11):

Yes.  See http://perlmonks.org/?node=References+quick+reference for some basic rules for accessing such data structures, but to create it, just do one of these:

```
%hash = ( 'somekey' => \@arrayvalue );
$hash{'somekey'} = \@arrayvalue;
%hash = ( 'somekey' => [ ... ] );
```

Answer (score -1):

```
use Data::Dumper; @name=('5/17',
    '5/17','5/17','5/17','5/17','5/17','5/17','5/17'); @status_flags=('U
    H L','U C','U H L','U C','U C','U H L','U C', 'U H L');
    @ip_address=('192.168.0.11','192.168.0.2','192.168.0.13','192.168.0.0','192.168.0.3','192.168.0.12','192.168.0.4','192.168.0.14'); @dp_id=('0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0');
    @ip_prefix_length=('32','32','32','24', '32', '32','32','32');

    for ($value=0;$value<=5;$value++) {


    $keyvals{'Response'}{'brocade-extension-ip-route'}{'extension-ip-route'}={'name'=>"$name[$value]"};
           $keyvals{'Response'}{'brocade-extension-ip-route'}{'extension-ip-route'}={'dp-id'=>"$dp_id[$value]"};
          $keyvals{'Response'}{'brocade-extension-ip-route'}{'extension-ip-route'}={'ip-address'=>"$ip_address[$value]"};
           $keyvals{'Response'}{'brocade-extension-ip-route'}{'extension-ip-route'}={'ip-prefix-length'=>"$ip_prefix_length[$value]"};


    $keyvals{'Response'}{'brocade-extension-ip-route'}{'extension-ip-route'}={'ip-gateway'=>'*'};




    }
        print Dumper \%keyvals;

    Each array value assign into hash value. $var1= {
              'Response' => {
                            'extension-ip-route' => {
                                                    'status-flags' =>  'U H L '
                                                                    ,
                                                    'ip-gateway' => '*',
                                                    'name' => '0/2',
                                                    'ip-address' =>  '192.168.20.11',
                                                    'dp-id' => '0',
                                                    'ip-prefix-length'=>'32'

                                                  }
                          }
            };
```