# How do I store an array as a value in a Perl hash?

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I'm trying to create a hash in Perl, whose values are arrays. Something like:

```
my @array = split(/;/, '1;2');
my $hash = {'a' => @array};
```

Surprisingly, this reports (using Data::Dumper):

```
$VAR1 = {
      'a' => '1',
      '2' => undef
    };
```

[This page](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1977) gives an example of storing an array in a hash by defining the array use square brackets, like:

```
my $hash = {'a' => ['1', '2']};
```

That works, but I'm getting my array from a call to the `split` method. What's magic about square brackets versus parentheses for defining an array, and how can I turn a "parentheses-array" into a 'square-brackets' array?

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Array in value of hash perl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13965196/array-in-value-of-hash-perl)

Comment: Parentheses define an array.  Square brackets define an array reference.

Comment: Terminology nit: Square brackets *return* an array reference, or even better, Square brackets *evaluate to* an array reference

Comment: @chilemagic Agreed. For some reason, that wasn't a top hit when I searched for similar questions.

Answer (score 2):

The values of hash (and array) elements are scalars, so you can't store an array into a hash.

The following are all equivalent:

```
my $hash = { a => @array };
my $hash = { 'a', @array };
my $hash = { 'a', $array[0], $array[1] };
my $hash = { a => $array[0], $array[1] => () };
```

A common solution is to store a reference to the array.

```
my @array = split(/;/, '1;2');
my $hash = { a => \@array };   # my $hash = { a => [ '1', '2' ] };
```

`[ LIST ]` similarly create an array, assigns `LIST` to it, then returns a reference to the array.