# How do I access an array in an array of hash in perl?

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I have an array of hash that one of the value of hash is an array .
-> I push "@title" to "part"
and for print ,
-> I put each of books{part} in a temporary array to access each element of title but it just print the first element
I can't access all element of "title" in array "books"

```
@books = ();
@title = (1,2,3,4,5);
push @books,{subject=>"hello" , part =>@title };
for($i=0;$i<scalar(@books);++$i)
{
    print $books[$i]{subject};

    @temp = $books[$i]{part};
    for($j=0;$j<scalar(@temp);++$j)
    {
        print $temp[$j]; #this print just first element "1"
    }
}
```

Comment: See also: [How do I store an array as a value in a Perl hash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28480241/how-do-i-store-an-array-as-a-value-in-a-perl-hash).

Comment: there is another problem:for each book it print the information of last book

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that the Hash reference you are pushing on the `@books` array is not be created correctly.

The Hash reference you are creating looks like this:

```
 {  'subject' => 'hello',
    'part'    => 1,
    '2'       => 3,
    '4'       => 5,
 }
```

when you probably expected it to look like this:

```
{  'subject' => 'hello',
   'part' => [
        1,
        2,
        3,
        4,
        5,
    ],
}
```

This is happening because values in Hashes and Arrays *have to be* SCALAR values. To create the Hash reference correctly to need to store a *reference* to the `@title` Array under the key `part`, you create a reference with a `\`:

```
push @books, { subject => "hello", part => \@title };
```

Note: This also means that when you want to extract the `part` key into the `@temp` Array you need to de-reference it (since it is an Array reference):

```
@temp = @{ $books[$i]{part} };
```