# Need help getting perl array out of scalar context

Tags: arrays, perl, scalar-context

I have a perl array I need to store in the following way:

```
 $self->{spec}->{allImages} = @allImages;
```

Then I need to retrieve the contents later:

```
 print Dumper($self->{spec}->{allImages});
```

This yields:

```
 $VAR1 = 10;
```

(the number of items in the array).

How can I break out of scalar context and get $self->{spec}->{allImages} back as a list?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Array in value of hash perl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13965196/array-in-value-of-hash-perl)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Each hash value can only be a scalar.

You must store a reference to the array:

```
$self->{spec}->{allImages} = \@allImages;
```

http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html will give you more tutorial.

Comment: Or a copy, `[ @allImages ]`, which is sometimes what you want instead. The reference is a stand in for the array so if you change it through a ref, the real array and therefore all its referents change as well.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the assignment:

```
$self->{spec}->{allImages} = \@allImages;
```

This creates an array-ref that you can use.